# "This Plug In not Supported" error in .swf player for the browser launched from Selenium2Library

Tags: flash, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, selenium2library

I am using Selenium2Library for my project from last 2 years. Also, updating my library and browser on regular basis.

Recently, I am encountering an issue where .swf files not loaded in browser which is launched by selenium. I am using latest Chrome browser "v54" and Chrome Driver v2.25.

However, .swf loads as expected on launching it manually (Normal Browser interaction). I believe some settings/configuration is missing.

SNAPSHOT:
[image]

I see some solution in  this link https://techhelpkb.com/this-plug-in-is-not-supported/, but no luck

Any help here highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

for a strange reason Adobe flash version was different in Manually launched browser and selenium launched browser. One showing Version 24 and other showing 23. (Used chrome://plugins/ to find out the versions)

Updated chrome with latest flash (selected ppapi flash version). Now suites are up and running